# how do I make getUserChoice (using the .forEach and eventListener) return a valid argument (string) that can be used by 'playRound()`?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm re-doing a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game this time adding an UI with DOM methods.
I have a function `getComputerChoice()` that works and returns a lowercase string with one of the three options randomly.

I have another function `PlayRound(computerChoice, userChoice)` that takes both strings returned and does some comparisons over them.

```
function playRound(computerChoice, userChoice) {


        if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
            console.log("----------------");
            console.log("Draw!");
            console.log("User choice was: " + userChoice);
            console.log("Computer choice was: " + computerChoice);
            console.log("----------------");
```

Finally I have a `getUserChoice()` function that I'm updating. It used to look like:

```
        function getUserChoice() {
        let userChoice = prompt("What is your weapon? ");
        return userChoice.toLowerCase();
    }
```

And the program worked with that.

Now, instead of a prompt the user can click one of three buttons. I changed the button so that I get the id of each button which matches one of either three choices

```
//USER CHOICE METHOD
function getUserChoice() {
    const userChoice = document.querySelectorAll('button');

    userChoice.forEach((choice) => {
        choice.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(choice.id);

        })
    })
}
```

The thing is that with this function "as-is" the `playRound()`'s `userChoice` is `undefined`, and in:

```
       function getUserChoice() {
        const userChoice = document.querySelectorAll('button');

        userChoice.forEach((choice) => {
            choice.addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log("this: " + this.id);
                console.log(choice.id);

            })
        })
    }
```

'
`this` is undefined.

My question is, how do I make `getUserChoice` (using the `.forEach` and `eventListener`) return a valid argument (string) that can be used by 'playRound()`?

The html:

```
    <div class="buttons">
    <button  id="rock">Rock</button>
    <button  id="paper">Paper</button>
    <button  id="scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `this` isn't passed to arrow functions. Either use a traditional function, use the `choice` variable, or use an `event` parameter to the callback function along with `event.target`.

Comment: `getUserChoice()` can set a global variable, which is then used by the code that calls `playRound()`.

Answer (score 2):

The actual question is **"how do I make getUserChoice (using the .forEach and eventListener) return a valid argument (string) that can be used by 'playRound()`?"**

The technical answer is you can't because the game code using `getUserChoice` is synchronous and relies on the call to `prompt` waiting for the user to make enter a choice. Synchronously waiting for users to click a button is **not supported in JavaScript** with limited exceptions caused by calling `prompt` or 'confirm` - some kind of asynchronous or event driven JavaScript processing will be needed to respond to user clicks.

Hence, although the problem presented within the question ("`this` is undefined) can be fixed, it is irrelevant to answering the question of how to proceed.

Learning how to program asynchronously in JavaScript is a wide field that I won't attempt to cover here. To move forward from the current situation I would suggest moving game control to the button click event listener (which should be added once rather than multiple times) and logging console messages before and during play to indicate the program is waiting for the user to make a choice.